# How to paste files in jre folder?

Tags: 11.10, java, filesystem, filemanager

I am trying to copy .jar and .so files into jre folder. I tried to do it like I do it in windows but it is not working, maybe the permission problem.
So how can I do it? using terminal or is there any other way? 
File which i want to copy is `RXTXcomm.jar` path is `/home/adi`
and I want to paste it in jre path is 
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext`

I am very new to Linux, I got it only couple of hours ago so please bear with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> `gksu cp /home/adi/RXTXcomm.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext`.

Or you can run it in the terminal:

`sudo cp /home/adi/RXTXcomm.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext`.

Comment: not yet let me try it

Comment: is there any way to do it without using terminal? it is so confusing..

Answer (score 0):

From command line (windows key to open dash, search for Terminal)

If the file is in /home/adi this will work:

```
cd /home/adi/
sudo RXTXcomm.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/
```

You need `sudo` if the destination is not owned by your user.